# Should we create a [regression-discontinuity] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

There are ~130 RD questions on the site (with some false positives) and it is [a standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_discontinuity_design) quasi-experimental inference method in economics and other fields. Does this volume merit its own tag?

Comment: Please note that there exists [tag:discontinuity] tag with 40 Qs. If you create [regression-discontinuity], you should probably check whether [discontinuity] is meaningfully different; perhaps most of these 40 threads can be moved to [regression-discontinuity] and the rest does not need to have this tag at all. In any case one needs to figure out what to do with [discontinuity] before creating [regression-discontinuity].

Comment: @gung I added the tag on one of the questions with a description. Once approved, I will start re-tagging the older questions.

Comment: Did we come to any conclusions about what to do w/ the `[discontinuity]` tag? Should we initiate another thread about that? (cc, @amoeba)

Comment: @gung To be honest I don't think it's worth another Meta thread. The tag currently has only 22 threads left. My feeling is that it's a diverse collection of topics which makes this tag not very useful (if it all), especially given that some of these 22 could/should be retagged as [changepoint] anyway. I'd get rid of it. But it's not an awful tag; no big harm if it stays either.

Comment: If we can come up w/ a useful, er, use for the tag, & can edit the excerpt to provide useful guidance, I'm fine w/ keeping it. If not, it would be better to remove it from all remaining threads & let it die, @amoeba.

Comment: @gung Well, okay, I went over these threads and removed [discontinuity] from all of them, retagging as appropriate. It really didn't have any coherent meaning and wasn't useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see why not.  That is a perfectly valid topic.  We have other, similar tags for methods used to infer causality from observational data, including:

- [causality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causality) (387 threads)
- [granger-causality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/granger-causality) (137 threads)
- [instrumental-variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrumental-variables) (292 threads)
- [propensity-scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propensity-scores) (201 threads)
- [difference-in-difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference-in-difference) (187 threads)
- [fixed-effects-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-effects-model) (511 threads)
- etc.

As always, if you do create the tag, please add a good excerpt to guide usage, and preferably a good full wiki as well.

---

It seems we already have a [discontinuity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discontinuity) tag with 40 threads (ht, @amoeba).  Of those, 22 have both `[regression]` and `[discontinuity]` and certainly more than half are really about RD.  There are also 17 threads with `[regression]` and "discontinuity", but without the tag.  I think it would be better to have an explicit `[r-d]` tag specifically for RD.  The term / idea of *discontinuity* is somewhat generic.  It could cover RD, but could also be used for something like [changepoint](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changepoint) or something else (e.g., [Is there a way to correct for continuity for the Shapiro-Wilk test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292784/is-there-a-way-to-correct-for-continuity-for-the-shapiro-wilk-test)).  If we did create a new tag for RD, the question then is what to do w/ `[d]`.  My first thought would be to go through those 40 threads and properly retag them, leaving `[d]` only on those threads like the one just linked that are about other senses of discontinuity and that can't be given a more specific tag.  Then we could edit the wiki excerpt to provide better usage guidance.

Comment: Agreed, regression-discontinuity is a relevant methodology in the Econometrics literature.

Comment: I upvoted several days ago, but now noticed that there exists [tag:discontinuity] tag with 40 Qs. One would need to figure out what to do with it before creating [regression-discontinuity].

Comment: Re Update: I agree but I'd say that in that case it would be better to eliminate [d] altogether. I am not sure there is any useful (useful for a tag) meaning of "discontinuity" once we take [r-d] out of it.

Comment: That's a viable option, @amoeba. I'm open to that. This was just my first thought.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the [regression discontinuity] rather than [r-d] or [rdd]. I think there is still room for [discontinuity]. There seem to be some questions about detecting structural breaks and their ilk, and that seems qualitatively different that making use of one that is known to exist.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov, "r-d" & "rdd" is just my shorthand b/c I'm too lazy to type "regression-discontinuity" each time. But I mean that the new tag should be `[regression-discontinuity]`.